# Нефиксированная высота элемента

Tags: html, css

Имеется блок div (главный)с фиксированной высотой,  в нем тоже несколько блоков, имеющие свою высоту и ширину. 
Как только фиксированную высоту главного div убираю, он исчезает. Разве он не должен растягиваться относительно самого длинного внутреннего элемента?

Comment: Значит на него влияют какие-то стили. Например, **float** какого-то из блоков

Comment: Спасибо, на самом деле float. Но как мне отказаться от него, если мне нужно спозиционировать элементы?

Comment: Зачем отказываться? Не по вашей теме, но совсем недавно [делал пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/e7mWw/1/). Обратите внимание на CSS-правило **#wrapper:after{...}**. Закоментируйте его и запустите (RUN). Увидите, что будет с блоком (он с бордером). Похоже на вашу ситуацию?

Comment: Похоже, блок исчезает. Но что делать не понял. Прописал также :after у себя в коде, результата 0

Comment: @Радик Камалов,  просто прописать - это не фокус )) В общем, для новичков есть способ проще: добавить после елемента с float, какой-нибудь элемент, аля:    <p style="clear: left / right / both"></p>Или же прочитайте про псевдоэлемент [:after](http://htmlbook.ru/css/after)

Comment: полезно будет почитать http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/blochnaya-verstka/plavayushchie-elementy

Answer (score 1):

Гуглите на тему "clearfix", "очищение потока". Есть несколько способов, лучше по-больше знать, что бы применять нужный